# Nginx subdomain redirect rule

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have 2 different server, Already added A record entry
I wanted redirect subdomain to different server.
I made changes in nginx configuration, but its still not working.

```
server {
    server_name example.com subdomain.example.com;
    return 301  https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
server {
    listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com subdomain.example.com;
    return 301  https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I'm not a nginx expert but usually you have to define the ports you want the server to listen to. Maybe you forgot that.